# "Drench" vs "Soak"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

I wonder which one of the two verbs below fits better in each sense and which one doesn't work in which sentence and why:

[**Soak:**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/soak) to make something **completely wet**.

[**Drench:**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/drench) To drench something or someone means to make them **completely wet**.

**1.** A car drove through a puddle and I got........... 
**a.** drenched 
**b.** soaked

**2.** When we got out of the river we were............ 
**a.** drenched 
**b.** soaked

**3.** The boy was ............ after playing in the rain. 
**a.** drenched 
**b.** soaked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between soak and drench is that **Soak** is used for something that absorbs water. (paper, cloth, wood etc) while **Drench** is used for others, like people etc.

Also, according [wikidiff](https://wikidiff.com/soak/drench),  "**soak** is to be saturated with liquid by being immersed in it while **drench** is to soak, to make very wet" (but not put/immerse the object in water, rather throw the water at them or them getting wet by a very sudden and quick process.)

So 1,3 would use drenched and 2 will use soak.

Comment: And conversely, you can put out a fire by drenching it, but you don't soak it.

Comment: Thank you @Bella Swan. One more question! Therefore as "soak" cannot be used for people, the sentence: "Take your umbrella or you'l **get soaked**." would be incorrect and instead I have to say: "Take your umbrella or you'l **get drenched (or simply wet)**." Right?

Comment: Also, when children or older people are doing waterplay, they are (drenching / wetting) each other. Where "drench" means "extremely/completely wet". Do you confirm @Bella Swan?

Comment: @A-friend by that sentence the person usually means that their clothes will be soaked in the rain. And it's used informally anyway. And yes, I agree that Drench means completely wet, but so does soak. It means completely wet too

Comment: @A-friend According to me, there's not a hard coded rule about the difference between them, it's just what makes more sense in some places as compared to the others.

Comment: But @Bella Swan how about the case when people are **playing with water guns** or when they are **doing an Ice-bucket challenge** or when they are **splashing around in a pool**? What they are doing? Are they **drenching wach other** or **getting each other wet**?

Comment: @A-friend Drenching probably. Using "wet" is always the safest option, though :)

Comment: @A-friend  "soak" can be used for people, but with a different meaning.  When someone **soaks** in a hot bath, it's not assumed that they absorb much of the bath water itself, but rather they absorb the heat from the water.

Comment: I would argue that in conversational English, either soak or drench would be acceptable in any of the examples.

Comment: +1 for all of you. Thank you very much @Andrew, Bella Swan and Luck for responding to this question.

Comment: One more question @Bella Swan. What structures do you normally used for passive and active usages of the two verbs "wet" and "drench"? I mean do you normally say e.g. "They **wet** each other" or "They **got** each other **wet**" or "They **made** each other **wet**" --- "They **wet** after the waterplay" or "They **got wet** after the waterplay"? Same for "drench"! "They **drenched** each other" or "They **got** each other **drenched**" or "They **made** each other **drenched**" --- "They **drenched** after the waterplay" or "They **got drenched** after the waterplay"?

Comment: Also, possibly my last question is that, as you mentioned, "soak" is not normally used for people. Then, why in this definition it is used? (**To get drenched/soaked/wet to the skin.** = 
extremely wet: - **Example:** > - We had no umbrellas so we got soaked to the skin in the pouring rain.) **Source:** Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: @A-friend all structures are correct. And as I said before, the person is not soaking water, rather their CLOTHES are getting soaked (that they are now sticking to the skin), but normally that would feel weird to put into a sentence, so "person soaked" is used usually.